# T in class? AddRange ICollection?

Tags: c#, .net, icollection

I try to do static class, add to icollection but i got some issues i cant seem to overcome. that is how i get so i can pass a ICollection in the method? cause T is that say it can not be resolved.

and then i wonder is there a way to do AddRange on icollection?

i was thinking of something like this but maby i am way out of my mind with it?

```
public static ICollection<T> add(this IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        ICollection<T> collection = null;

        return collection.AddRange(list);            
    }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, `ICollection<T>` doesn't have an `AddRange` method - and even if it did, you'd be trying to dereference `null` which will throw a `NullReferenceException`. You haven't specified a collection to add the list to... what exactly are you trying to do?

You could create (say) a new `List<T>` - and that has the benefit of already having a constructor which can take an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static ICollection<T> Add<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    return new List<T>(list);            
}
```

However, at that point you've really just reimplemented `Enumerable.ToList()` and given it a different return type...

If you want to add everything to an existing collection, you might want something like this:

```
public static ICollection<T> AddTo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list,
                                      ICollection<T> collection)
{
    foreach (T item in list)
    {
        collection.Add(item);
    }
    return collection;
}
```

Comment: Love the new name...had no idea who it was either. :-P

Comment: You are missing a generic method argument  :)

Comment: @Joel: Hence "at that point you've really just reimplemented Enumerable.ToList() and given it a different return type..." :)

Comment: In .Net 4.0 `List<T>` has an `AddRange` method - also `InsertRange`, `RemoveRange` ...actually, MSDN shows it available in 3.5

Comment: @IAbstract: Sure, but this is for `ICollection<T>`, not `List<T>`

Comment: duly noted :)  ...since `List<T>` implements `ICollection<T>` I thought it relevant.

Comment: Would it not be better to have the sig ``public static Q AddTo<T,Q>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Q collection) where Q : ICollection<T>``? This would help chaining if you wanted to keep the input and output type the same?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly you want to add a `IEnumerable<T>` to an empty collection.

Wouldn't it be easier to just do:

```
ICollection<MyObject> collection = new List<MyObject>(GetIEnumerableOfMyObject());
```

Or even:

```
ICollection<MyObject> collection = GetIEnumerableOfMyObject().ToList();
```

Comment: i did not know i could do a ICollection then do the list like that.

Comment: `List<T>` implements `ICollection<T>` so yup.

Answer (score 1):

The other ways seem to assume that your ICollection is empty and/or your ICollection is a type of List.  However, if you want AddRange, then you can Extend the ICollection class as follows:

```
public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> ic, IEnumerable<T> ie)
{
    foreach (T obj in ie)
    {
        ic.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

Note, however, that since List impliments ICollection, this may cause ambiguity when dealing directly with List objects (though I haven't tested yet if the compiler will be able to resolve it--my gut reaction is that it should, though, since AddRange is a member of List and the compiler will go through member functions first before looking at extensions, but if I'm wrong I'm sure someone will correct me).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the collection type of your source list an alternative approach is to use [`List(T).ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx), as in:

```
List<string> source = ...
ICollection<string> dest = ...

source.Foreach(dest.Add);
```

However, the readability of this is [easy to dispute](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).