# How do you insert an IEnumerable<T> into entity model collection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have an IEnumerable and I want to insert all the items into an Entity Model collection.
e.g.  Looking for a way to do the following:

```
var missingitems = IEnumerable<MissingItem>();
//Add lots of Missing Items
modelContext.MissingItems.AddList(missingitems);
```

Instead of having to do:

```
missingitems.ToList().ForEach(mi=>modelContext.MissingItems.Add(mi));
```

Comment: Check [Add range to ICollection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667614/t-in-class-addrange-icollection/1667634#1667634) answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `AddList` or `AddRange`. You can create your own extension method which will offer you your expected syntax but internally your new method will still call `AddObject` (or `Add` in DbContext) in loop because `AddObject` (`Add`) is not just adding to "collection".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
var missingitems = IEnumerable<MissingItem>();
//Add lots of Missing Items  
modelContext.MissingItems.AddList(missingitems.ToList());
```

Comment: I don't have AddList as an option under intellisense?  Just AddObject ?