# ICollection<T> doesn't have AddRange but List<T> does, is Casting Bad

Tags: c#

So in my class I have this private readonly member `ICollection<IMusicItem> playlist`. I would prefer to use the interface `ICollection<T>`.

I would like to use the `List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items)`. In my method would it be **dangerous** to cast the `ICollection` to a `List<T>` even if I instantiate the `ICollection<T>` as a `new List<T>()` in the constructor.

Is this bad practice, is there a better way of doing this?

Or is it just better to have a `List<T>`

Comment: Use an extension method perhaps, like in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1667634/996081)?

Comment: You can create an extension method `AddRange` for any `T` collection. A generic one.

Comment: What are your reasons to insist on the interface type on a **private** member, especially when you are instantiating a concrete type that would let you do what you want?

Comment: That is a very good point actually

Comment: @nodots I like the use of an interface, feels safer to me :P

Comment: I've had a really long day so my mind is a bit dead :P

Comment: @CallumLinington Interfaces are powerful tools, but it's not universally perferable to be using them.  The purpose of interfaces is to allow you to write code that only relies on the behavior of the interface, and that can be given multiple different concrete implementations that are transparent to it.  Here the interface doesn't provide the needed behavior, and you're relying on the behavior of the concrete type.  You should reflect that reliance in the type of the variable, rather than removing static typing and claiming you don't have a reliance on something you are in fact relying on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's bad practice, because it breaks encapsulation. Using an interface is good, but it's pointless if you have to cast the object back to a concrete type. Act as if you didn't know the concrete type, or it's a future bug waiting to happen if you decide to switch to another type later on.

Use an extension method instead:

```
public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
        collection.Add(item);
}
```

Note: It's better to expose interfaces in a public API so you're free to change the implementing object later, but it's a matter of style whether to do it on private fields. You may as well use the concrete class.

Comment: Note that this is notably reducing the performance over `LIst.AddRange`, as `List.AddRange` can prevent multiple resizes of the backing array unlike this method.

Comment: @Servy that's true, but only *if* `items is ICollection<T>`, also in that case `List<T>.AddRange` allocates an array for the new items, fills it with the sequence and then copies it back to the list, so you get 2 copies of the data.

Answer (score 3):

It's not dangerous (when done right), just pointless.

```
if (playlist is IList<IMusicItem>)
{
  (playList as IList<IMusicItem>).AddRange(items);
} 
else
{
   // still need a foreach here
}
```

The real issue is "I would prefer to use the interface `ICollection<T>`".

Why exactly? Your question suggests it always is a List, so why not expose it as such?

Exposing it as a more general `ICollection<>` only makes sense when other implementations than List might exist, and then the casting is useless.

Comment: Yeah, that was more what I was looking for. So my understanding is, expose interfaces to clients, but internally just use the concrete implementation.